# Can a C program be both a server and client at the same time?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm a learning C and just started reading about sockets.

I was wondering if a program can be coded to be both a server and a client at the same time. For example, a program starts off as a server but if it wanted to connect to another server, it could, in parallel, start a client to connect to other program's servers, while maintaining it's server status for others to connect too.

If so, how can that be done? With different processes?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Yes, a process can host any number (within reason) of server and/or client instances simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you @500-InternalServerError, there's no need for forking then? One same process could host both? What if the process needs to wait for the server or client to send something?

Comment: You would typically employ some sort of threading scheme so that not the entire process but only a specific thread is waiting for data coming in on a particular connection.

Comment: There is no such thing as a client/server, only sockets. So you can do whatever you want in one process.

Comment: I am sorry, there's no such thing as a socket server or client? I am confused because all the information I read about sockets talked about clients and servers...

Comment: @NuriaPolizzi: There absolutely are clients and servers, but those concepts are orthogonal to those of programs and processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the use cases for "threading" where there are multiple execution instances performing different jobs in concert. https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.

There is absolutely nothing which stops this.

If you want to manage more than one socket from the same process, you might find the `poll` function useful, or `select` on Windows. (`select` also works on Linux but `poll` is better in my opinion)